# PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, prepared-statement, psql

I am doing a "IN" query using prepared statements on rails. I am getting PG::InvalidTextRepresentation error.

code :

```
def mark_ineligible(match_ids)
  ids = match_ids.join(", ")
  result = epr("mark_matches_as_ineligible",
               "UPDATE matches SET is_eligibile=false WHERE id IN ( $1 )",
               [ids])
end

def epr(statementname, statement, params)
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
  begin
    result = connection.exec_prepared(statementname, params)
    return result
  rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName => e
    begin
      connection.prepare(statementname, statement)
    rescue PG::DuplicatePstatement => e
      # ignore since the prepared statement already exists
    end
    result = connection.exec_prepared(statementname, params)
    return result
  end
end
```

trying to invoke this using :

```
match_ids = [42, 43]
mark_ineligible match_ids
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "42, 43"

    from (irb):24:in `exec_prepared'
    from (irb):24:in `rescue in epr'
    from (irb):15:in `epr'
    from (irb):8:in `mark_ineligible'
    from (irb):35
```

Please help here. I want to know why I am getting this errors and how to fix it.

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of passing `[ids]` ,try passing `ids` since it is an array.

Comment: hi, "ids" is a comma separated string.  I am expecting final query to look like "UPDATE matches SET is_eligibile=false WHERE id IN ( 42, 43 )"

Comment: @ansul410 `ids = match_ids.join(", ")` - just remove this from your `mark_ineligible` method and directly pass `match_ids` to your query.

Comment: @dkp , doing this I get an error :
PG::ProtocolViolation: ERROR:  bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "mark_matches_as_ineligible" requires 1

Comment: I want to create my sql query using one param only, but it should be able to update multiple rows.

Comment: please check my answer below. Instead of sending multiple arguments, rather you should pass an array as argument

Answer (score 0):

`mark_ineligible` should look as follows:

```
def mark_ineligible(match_ids)
    result = epr("mark_matches_as_ineligible",
           "UPDATE matches SET is_eligibile=false WHERE id IN ( $1 )", match_ids)
end
```

And when you call `mark_ineligible`, pass an array as argument:

```
mark_ineligible(match_ids)  #=>match_ids = [42,43]
```